# Match parts of code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match parts of code with regex. How can I match var, a, =, 2 and ; from

```
"var a = 2;"
```

?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve, because this seems incredibly speculative (especially given that *you* don't seem sure what you want to ask)? Please see the Meta question: "[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"

Comment: What did you try ? `\S+`

Comment: do you want to match this `var a = 2;`? is it part of script or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this regexp: `/\S+/g`

To break it down: `\S` selects all non-whitespace characters, `+` makes sure you it selects multiple non whitespace characters together (i.e. 'var'),
and the 'g' flag makes sure it selects *all* of the occurrences in the string, and instead of stopping at the first one which is the default behavior.

This is a helpful link for playing around until you find the right regexp: https://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: Close. Just looked again and it's matching 2 and ; together.

Comment: It would help to understand exactly what you want to achieve here, but if all you want is to match each part individually, then this will do it: `/(\w+|[=;])/g`. If you want to also recognize other individual operators you can add them inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "var a = 2;";

// clean the duplicate whitespaces
var no_duplicate_whitespace = str.replace(new RegExp("\\s+", "g"), " ");

// and split by space
var tokens = no_duplicate_whitespace.split(" ");
```

Or as @kuujinbo pointed out:

```
str.split(/\s+/);
```